# Best way to implement validation in a class?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a design issue in my application.
I have a class with fields having some kind of business logic validations.
This class is instantiated and filled with data in two ways..
1st: By consumer of the class: Data sent from Front end and populated into the object and saved in Database.
2nd: While fetching the stored data.
In 2nd requirement I have a problem.
I don't want to validate data since it may be possible the data stored may not comply to the business logic due to deletion or modification in existing data.
So I need to populate the object with saved data without validation.

so kindly suggest me best way to add validation logic in a class, so that when it is used for data save then it should be validated, and when fetching data it should not validate any of the fields if the key field exists in database table.
Eg:

```
class customer
{
    private string customerCode;
    private string customerName;
    private List<Project> projectList;
    //These property contains validation logic for data assigned to them.
    public string CustomerCode{get; set;}
    public string CustomerName{get; set;}
    public List<Project> projectList{get;set;};

    public bool SetData(ref string message)
    {
        //Fetch From Database and set it to fields.
        //Here to avoid validation I can use fields directly to skip validation.
        this.CustomerCode = DataTable[CustomerCode];
        this.CustomerName = DataTable[CustomerName];

        //But here its not possbible to skip validation in Project class
        foreach(projectID in DataTable[Projects])
        {
            //**Problem Area**.... every project I add is validated according to business logic, but it may be possible that even after completion of a project users of the system want to list all the projects of that customer.
            this.ProjectList.Add(new Project(projectID));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about the Validation Application Block: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648831.aspx

Comment: Thanx, but the content is outdated, I just don't want to include any framework instead want to address this issue in my design

Comment: It sounds to me like you are not separating your concerns enough. You have one object that is hydrated from a Database call, so it should be created via constructor with your parameters. The other situation is where you could have partially hydrated data coming from the user. Using the same type for both situations does not seem ideal.

Comment: It means do u want to recommend to use two different classes for same a single entity and provide different implementation, 1st to read data, 2nd to Save data?

Comment: @Tejs Actually problem is with the Project class here, it contains validation but while fetching from database it may be possible that project is completed or expired. So while adding project in ProjectList of customer it will generate error. which I want to skip. But while updating a project I need that constructor to validate the project data.

Comment: An entity is just a representation of data. Validation is something that happens to an entity. So validation should not be wrapped up inside an Entity I think.

Comment: @Tejs one of the reason to add properties in C# was this purpose, to validate data while assigning them to fields.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh That's true, but it doesn't mean it's always appropriate. In this case, if you don't want validation to activate every time you use the Project object, make validation another object's responsibility, and only invoke it when desired.

Comment: @DanJ So how do you suggest me to implement validation?  A Validate function to validate whole data of entity or some kind of wrapper class or derived class?

Comment: In this example, make the `Project` a 'dumb' object that just contains the data (either from user input or an existing database record). Create a `ProjectValidator` which takes a `Project` as an input and tells you whether or not it's valid. Then, at the point where you actually care about validation (user input), create a `Project` out of the user's input data and pass it to the `ProjectValidator`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that sounds good. Thanks. Well earlier I was not in favor of removing validation from properties backing the fields because I doubted that I am making some design mistake. But after this discussion I think It is required in such scenarios. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more general way to see the problem is for an object to have two validation strategies. In this case you say that the second strategy would be to just ignore any validation. However, in the future you might find it useful to add some minor or side validations, hence the idea of the more general approach. As Davis Osborne suggests, the best way to validate objects is by creating specific validation classes. In sum, I would create two validation objects and validate my object with the appropriate one, depending on the context. In this way your methods will be prepared to use any validation you happen to include in the future and the only you will need is to update would be the validation side of your design.

Comment: Yes, your strategy sounds same as I finally decided to model this problem.

Comment: Excellent. Validation is a whole topic in itself. I didn't want to go in further details because you said you wanted something simple. That's a good approach for getting started. In the long run naïve solutions may fall short. If that happens you will naturally identify the need for a more elaborated validation framework.

Comment: You could get an idea of the framework I use by reading [Extreme Validation](http://knowledge.caesarsystems.com/caesarsystems/resources/kb-documents/extreme-validation). Also, the book [A Mentoring Course on Smalltalk](http://www.lulu.com/shop/andres-valloud/a-mentoring-course-on-smalltalk-pdf/ebook/product-18783337.html) has a chapter devoted to validations.

Answer (score 0):

Create a specific validator that sits behind a common interface. Then it can be unit tested and potentially replaced to provide custom validation scenarios, if this strategy were needed.

Provide support for validating the class as a whole and for each property.